# zsh: populate search input with existing line contents when ^R is pressed?

Tags: zsh, command-history, zle

Given .zshrc config:

```
bindkey -v
bindkey "^R" history-incremental-pattern-search-backward
```

When I type `foo<^R>bar` at an empty prompt, it searches for the most recent command matching `bar`.

How can I make ^R use the existing prompt input? I.e. with that key sequence I want to match `foobar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you bind `^R` to `history-beginning-search-backward`, it comes close, but that's not a pattern search.

You can bind `^R` to a function that adds the current content of the line as the initial search pattern.

```
history-incremental-pattern-search-backward-from-line () {
  zle history-incremental-pattern-search-backward $BUFFER
}
zle -N history-incremental-pattern-search-backward-from-line
bindkey -M viins "^R" history-incremental-pattern-search-backward-from-line
bindkey -M vicmd "^R" history-incremental-pattern-search-backward-from-line
bindkey -M isearch "^R" history-incremental-pattern-search-backward
```

(You need that binding to the `isearch` map because otherwise a repeated `^R` would base its search on the line you've found so far, instead of repeating the current search.)